# Old maid card game

Tags: python-3.x

[image: image of question and code]

I am trying to write an old maid card game. Now I reach the stage of removing pairs, so if there are same numbers (2-10) and same letters(AKQJ), delete both of them. I have written several lines of code, but it does not work. Could you tell me why and help me fix it.

How can I identify the same number with different suits and delete both of them in the same list?

```
def x(alist):
    n = '2345678910AKJQ'
    a=[]
    b=[]
    for i in alist:
      j = ''.join([k for k in i if k in n])
      if not j in b:
        a.append(i)
        b.append(j)
    return a
```

Answer (score 0):

create a default dictionary creating a list, split the items according to last character (I used standard letters not symbols), and compose a listcomp with keys where there's only 1 value.

```
import re
from collections import defaultdict

deck = ['10H','AS','AH','4C','4S','5D']


dd = defaultdict(list)

for d in deck:
   dd[d[:-1]].append(d[-1])

print([k for k,v in dd.items() if len(v)==1])
```

result:

```
['5', '10']
```